# Nein, so doch nicht!—No, not at all!

Tags: meaning, modal-particle

Is this the most accurate English translation? Is it accurate at all?

Comment: I don't get the thing with down votes. If I'm not welcome here, I'm not gonna ask questions any more.

Comment: Welcome to SE German Language Abstract. You can (and should) read about what are considered good _on-topic_ questions at this site in our [help]. It's nothing personal, but about the content you're posting.

Comment: Hi Abstract, welcome to this forum. - This forum is not intended for providing translations or for doing spellchecking or proofreading. This forum is intended for questions (and answers) about German language (grammar, expression, etc.). A good question highlights a general problem. Also,a good question has the potential to be of use or interest for other readers. And third, a good question demonstrates your own preliminary efforts to solve the problem.

Comment: @Abstract Yes, it has something of Wikipedia -- arbitrary and not really plausible. That's why I don't ask questions anymore.

Comment: Thank you for welcoming me, but I was already "welcomed" by being virtually kicked out. I asked those questions to explore possible contexts in which different English translations could or couldn't apply. Those sentences puzzle me and quite some people use them to study German currently.

Comment: @Abstract Don't grieve about the downvotes. Perhaps people criticized that it is more a question about English than about German.

Comment: @Paul Frost it's not downvotes per se, it's the fact that I got banned from asking questions with the text like "...you might need a break - take a breather...not been received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own pace..." and I interpreted it as "you're a nuisance, and you're slow" :) I have a short fuse :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's rather

No, not like that!

It implies that you're doing something but in the wrong way ("so").